# How to encode a URL with accent characters in Javascript?

Tags: internet-explorer, url, encoding

I am having a strange issue with IE with the URL where if I pass scenario in the URL it does not work and it seems to work perfectly for other browsers.

IN IE the URL comes up as :

.../search.aspx?keyword=sc%c3%83%c2%a9nario

In FireFox URL comes up as :

.../search.aspx?keyword=sc%C3%A9nario

In IE the URL breaks and Firefox works fine, do i have to do URL decoding to take care of this in IE ?

Comment: How do you pass it in the URL?

Answer (score 3):

Although you did not say how you "passed" the string, I can tell you what happened.

The character `é` has codepoint E9.  In UTF-8, this is encoded as two bytes: C3 A9.  So the correct way to show "scénario" in a URL is

```
sc%C3%A9nario
```

Now, what would happen if you took this string and looked at each individual byte and assumed they were characters, and did a UTF-8 encoding a *second time*?  What would happen is

- s -> s
- c -> c
- %C3 would be interpreted as the char with codepoint C3, namely Ã, which in UTF-8 is C3 83.
- %A9 would be interpreted as the char with codepoint A9, namely ©, which in UTF-8 is C2 A9.
- n -> n
- etc.

This corresponds exactly with what you saw in IE.

Now I can't say for sure how this happened because there was not enough background in the question, but what is clear is that somehow, the string "scénario" got encoded into a UTF-8 byte string *and then it got encoded again* based on the weird assumption that the first encoding produced a character string in the Windows-1252 or Latin-1 encoding.

You need to look into how your string got "encoded twice."